# Xcode folder structure for adding a library

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios, directory-structure

I'm creating an iPhone app in X-Code. I have downloaded the [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/) library to make requests to my web server. What should my folder structure look like after adding this library? If I were to take a wild guess on the general best practice, it should either be like this:

- Classes

  - ASIHTTPRequest

    - ASHTTPRequestClass1.h
    - ASHTTPRequestClass1.m
    - ASHTTPRequestClass2.h
    - ASHTTPRequestClass2.m
    - ...
- Other Sources
- Resources
- Frameworks
- Products

OR

- Classes
- Other Sources
- Resources
- Frameworks

  - ASIHTTPRequest

    - ASHTTPRequestClass1.h
    - ASHTTPRequestClass1.m
    - ASHTTPRequestClass2.h
    - ASHTTPRequestClass2.m
    - ...
- Products

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally I only put compiled products in my *Frameworks* folder. Uncompiled classes part of a "library" I usually put into a *Utility* folder in the root of my project. I should add that recently I've been using more and more code from sources like github for use in my projects. I like to put these kinds of projects in the root of my **Development** folder, e.g. like this:

```
in the folder 'Development':
/project_1 /* my project that makes use of json and egocache */
/project_2 /* my project that makes use of json and three20 */
/project_3 /* my project that makes use of three20 and egocache */
/...
/json-lib-github
/egocache-lib-github
/three20-lib-github 
etc...
```

In my projects that make use of the libraries I create references to these projects, again the references are created inside the Utility folder in the root of my current project. This way all my projects can share the github code and I can easily update these libraries for all my projects at once.

Answer (score 0):

It is safe to add in your classes folder and use in your code with including header.